# UrlEncode of link ids with ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper extension methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have actions that take string id parameters that are based on a username which can include characters that require encoding, for instance "user?1"

If I use `ActionLink()` to generate the links, passing the string without encoding, it generates a link like this: `http:\\localhost\controller\action\user?1`, and the action gets passed "user" as the id.

If I `UrlEncode()` the string before passing it to `ActionLink`, then the link generated is: `http:\\localhost\controller\action\user%253f1` as ActionLink will then encode the '%' character for you.  Besides this looking ugly, it then also generates a HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request when following the link which I've not yet tracked down the cause of.

Is there any way that I can generate the url like: `http:\\localhost\controller\action\user%3f1`?

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the ? character or replacing it with something else like a dash (-) or underscore (_) ?

Comment: The idea is that the url slug is actually a user generated string, in the current case it is their username.  I'm unfortunately not in the position of being able to constrain the characters allowed as it is a n existing system with existing users.

Comment: The worry with replacing characters is that what if someone tries to register a new account as user-1 or user_1 ?  What would their url slug be if I had used one of those for user?1 ?

Comment: how about disallowing ? in the username then?

Comment: do you need to allow the '?' in the username

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the Global.asax.cs file

add another route for your convenience, in this case, the ff. might work:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
             null,                            
             "{controller}/{action}/user/{id}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
         );
```

I guess this is what you want, to separate action for each users, but i suggest you use cookie for this purpose.

PS: Remember to put that one on top of your default route since routing is trying to match from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a jquery plugin that check all the links and replace the char that you need to replace with the new value.
and after apply this plugin to all the ActionLinks