# How does Stackoverflow escape tag names in urls

Tags: .net, url

I want to generate a url from a tag name.

In my view (asp.net mvc) I have the following:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(tagName), 
"tagged" //action, 
"posts" //controller, 
new {tagName=Html.UrlEncode(tagName)} //querystring argument, 
new {@class="tag"} //html attributes) 
%>
```

But this generates the following URL if the tagName is "c#" (without the quotes):

```
http://localhost/posts/tagged/c%2523
```

which results in Http 400 error - Bad Request

On Stackoverflow, the url for the same "c#" tag generates "c%23" instead of "c%2523"

I tried Html.UrlEncode, Uri.EscapeDataString, Uri.EscapeUrlString, but none of those produces the desirable "c%23" format.

So how should I encode the tagName for the anchor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're doing two encodes of your URL as c%2523 is the encoded value for c%23. (0x23 = ASCII 35 = #, 0x25 = ASCII 37 = %). As you have two encode calls (Html.Encode and Html.UrlEncode), perhaps removing one of them removes your problem.

Comment: if I don't escape it at all, it outputs c# unescaped, and the hash becomes the url fragment

Comment: The first Html.Encode is for the link text, so it has nothing to do with the href part of the anchor

Comment: Yes, also noticed that. I haven't used ASP yet, so I can only guess. By the way, can you try something like 'new {tagName="c%23"}' for testing purposes?

Comment: Hmm... good test. I put "c%23" manually in there and it still escaped it with "c%2523". But if I put "c#" it doesn't escape it at all. Seems like there's some kind of "logic" inside the Html.ActionLink helper class in there.

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406711/urlencode-of-link-ids-with-asp-net-mvc-htmlhelper-extension-methods - but there is no solution to it, so it won't help much.

Comment: I did a quick peek into the mvc source code, and it seems they are doing Html.AttributeEncode (for the "href" part) before it gets output. Maybe that's what is causing the trouble. I may skip the ActionLink helper altogether if I don't find a way around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

# corresponds to the ascii value of 23 in hex.  So I guess they use the hex value.

Answer (score 0):

If i recal correctly, then will actionlink automaticly encode the values on the url, so just remove the Html.Encode(tagName), and it should look nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(tagName), 
"tagged" //action,  
"posts" //controller, 
new {tagName=Html.UrlEncode(tagName)} //querystring argument, 
new {@class="tag"} //html attributes) 
%>
```

Html.ActionLink creates HTML and deals with the escaping issues for you. You should not explicitly Html.Encode the link text, or Html.UrlEncode the parameter.

If a ‘#’ in a parameter value is not being escaped that sounds like a bug in ActionLink() and you might have to generate the link yourself.

Comment: I saw that it Html.AttributeEncode() all attributes of the link, so there lies the problem. The "c#" string won't be escaped as it's a valid attribute string, but if I URL-encode "c#" first, it will then AttributeEncode() the already escaped string. I have to skip the helper altogether in this case

Comment: AttributeEncode is a completely different process to UrlEncode. First you UrlEncode the parts of URL you wish to use to get a valid URL. Then you AttributeEncode-or-HtmlEncode every attribute value, whether it's a URL or not. AttributeEncode is only about ‘"<&’ and will not touch ‘#’ or ‘%23’.

Comment: Well clearly the ActionLink helper is doing "something" in there that messes it up. I skipped it and used "<a href="...">...</a>" and I did my work..